# Why pointer generates an error "invalid indirect"?

Tags: arrays, pointers, go

`p` is a pointer which points to array `arr`, we can get array `arr` by using `*p`, but why can not get second element by using `*p[2]`?

It will cause an error :

> invalid indirect of p[1] (type int)

The following code:

```
arr := [4]int{1,2,3,4}
var p *[4]int = &arr
fmt.Println(p)     // output &[1 2 3 4]
fmt.Println(*p)    // output [1 2 3 4]
fmt.Println(p[1])  // output 2
fmt.Println(*p[1]) //generate an error:invalid indirect of p[1] (type int)
```

Answer (score 11):

Because `*p[1]` means `*(p[1])`. And `(p[1])` is an `int` which you can't dereference.

Use parenthesis to dereference the pointer first, and index the result:

```
fmt.Println((*p)[1])
```

Also note that `p[1]` without parenthesis and dereferencing is allowed and works because `p` is a pointer to an [array](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Array_types), and quoting from [Spec: Index expressions:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions)

> For a of [pointer](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Pointer_types) to array type:
>
> - `a[x]` is shorthand for `(*a)[x]`

But note that the same is not allowed for pointer to slice types.

Comment: Thanks, and i have other question bellow:

`type treeNode struct {
 value int
 left, right *treeNode
}
func main() {
 var root treeNode
 root = treeNode{value:3}
 root.left = &treeNode{}
 root.right = &treeNode{5,nil,nil}
 fmt.Println(root.right)  //output &{5 <nil> <nil>}
 fmt.Println(*(root.right))  //output {5 <nil> <nil>}
 fmt.Println(root.right.value)  //output 5
 fmt.Println(*(root.right).value)  //invalid indirect of root.right.value (type int)
}`

why *(root.right).value also cause invalid indirect ?

Comment: @Nevs Because `*(root.right).value` is the same as `*( (root.right).value )`, where `value` is of type `int` which you can't dereference. Instead simply use `root.right.value`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have created an array of numbers, not pointers to numbers. It is not an array of reference types. Saying fmt.Println(*p[1]) is like saying 'print the thing p[1] points to' which is wrong because p[1] isn't a pointer.